# How to use NsdManager to detect an emulated device on a private network?

Tags: java, android, mdns, zeroconf

I'm currently working on a mobile app that discover's and resolve's a device on a private network. The app currently works perfect and will allow me to connect a socket to this device.

Now I'm working on a feature that can't legally be implemented until OSHA approves it. So to get around this we have emulated devices we can use in the place of an actual physical device. This emulator works on a Windows tablet using [bonjour](https://github.com/watson/bonjour), but my app using Android's `NsdManager`, will discover the emulated device and attempt to resolve it but I never get a response from the call to `resolveService()`. Neither `onResolveFailed` or `onServiceResolved` are called. With an actual physical device the app works without issue.

Are there any known issues this might cause this to not work with an emulated device? Or maybe something else that I could look into for a possible solution for this?

**EDIT**
So in order for this to work correctly the app and a Windows laptop are both connected to a WiFi router so the laptop and phone/tablet can be on the same network. Here is the log when connecting through the WiFi router to the emulated device on that laptop:

**08-24 08:35:04.428 12514-12625/com.tsi.fitpro D/ZeroConf: About to resolve service.

08-24 08:35:04.431 455-1484/? D/MDnsDS: resolveService(18, (null), emulator-name, _telnet._tcp., local.)

08-24 08:35:04.433 455-1484/? D/MDnsDS: startMonitoring 18
    triggering rescan
    resolveService successful

08-24 08:35:04.433 455-1483/? D/MDnsDS: Monitor poll got data pollCount = 2, 1

08-24 08:35:04.434 455-1483/? D/MDnsDS: controlSocket shows revent= 1

    MDnsSdListener::Monitor got 1

    MDnsSdListener::Monitor poll rescanning - size=15, live=2

    Going to poll with pollCount 3

    Monitor poll got data pollCount = 3, 1

    Monitor found [1](https://github.com/watson/bonjour).revents = 1 - calling ProcessResults

    resolve succeeded for 18 finding emulator-name._telnet._tcp.local. at LaptopName.:3603 with txtLen 1

    controlSocket shows revent= 0

    Going to poll with pollCount 3

08-24 08:35:04.437 783-1663/? E/NsdServiceInfo: While parsing txt records (pos = 1): Zero sized txt record

08-24 08:35:04.438 455-1484/? D/MDnsDS: Stopping resolve with ref 0xb300c52c

    freeServiceRef 18

    triggering rescan

08-24 08:35:04.438 455-1483/? D/MDnsDS: Monitor poll got data pollCount = 3, 2

    Monitor found [1](https://github.com/watson/bonjour).revents = 32 - calling ProcessResults

08-24 08:35:04.439 455-1483/? W//system/bin/netd: dnssd_clientstub DNSServiceProcessResult called with invalid DNSServiceRef 0xb3029070 FFFFFFFF DDDDDDDD

08-24 08:35:04.439 455-1483/? D/MDnsDS: controlSocket shows revent= 1

    MDnsSdListener::Monitor got 1

    MDnsSdListener::Monitor poll rescanning - size=15, live=1

    Going to poll with pollCount 2

08-24 08:35:04.443 455-1484/? D/MDnsDS: getAddrInfo(19, (null) 0, LaptopName.)

    startMonitoring 19

    triggering rescan

    getAddrInfo successful

08-24 08:35:04.443 455-1483/? D/MDnsDS: Monitor poll got data pollCount = 2, 1

    controlSocket shows revent= 1

08-24 08:35:04.444 455-1483/? D/MDnsDS: MDnsSdListener::Monitor got 1

    MDnsSdListener::Monitor poll rescanning - size=15, live=2

    Going to poll with pollCount 3

08-24 08:35:04.883 783-783/? D/WifiTrafficPoller: notifyOnDataActivity() - mBusMaxLock.acquire()

08-24 08:35:05.232 783-1630/? D/wifi: onLinkStatsResults: radio_stat.on_time = 9651912

    onLinkStatsResults: radio_stat.tx_time = 0

    onLinkStatsResults: radio_stat.rx_time = 0

    android_net_wifi_getLinkLayerStats: radio_stat.on_time = 9651912

    android_net_wifi_getLinkLayerStats: radio_stat.tx_time = 0

    android_net_wifi_getLinkLayerStats: radio_stat.rx_time = 0**

And here is the log connecting through the WiFi router to an actual device. This works.

**08-24 08:47:55.744 19492-19583/com.tsi.fitpro D/ZeroConf: actual-device-name

    About to resolve service.

08-24 08:47:55.747 455-1484/? D/MDnsDS: resolveService(21, (null), actual-device-name, _telnet._tcp., local.)

08-24 08:47:55.749 455-1484/? D/MDnsDS: startMonitoring 21

    triggering rescan

    resolveService successful

08-24 08:47:55.749 455-1483/? D/MDnsDS: Monitor poll got data pollCount = 2, 1

    controlSocket shows revent= 1

    MDnsSdListener::Monitor got 1

    MDnsSdListener::Monitor poll rescanning - size=15, live=2

    Going to poll with pollCount 3

    Monitor poll got data pollCount = 3, 1

    Monitor found [1](https://github.com/watson/bonjour).revents = 1 - calling ProcessResults

    resolve succeeded for 21 finding actual-device-name._telnet._tcp.local. at actual-device-name.local.:3603 with txtLen 1

08-24 08:47:55.750 455-1483/? D/MDnsDS: controlSocket shows revent= 0

    Going to poll with pollCount 3

08-24 08:47:55.752 783-1663/? E/NsdServiceInfo: While parsing txt records (pos = 1): Zero sized txt record

08-24 08:47:55.753 455-1484/? D/MDnsDS: Stopping resolve with ref 0xb300c514

    freeServiceRef 21

    triggering rescan

08-24 08:47:55.754 455-1483/? D/MDnsDS: Monitor poll got data pollCount = 3, 2

    Monitor found [1](https://github.com/watson/bonjour).revents = 32 - calling ProcessResults

08-24 08:47:55.754 455-1483/? W//system/bin/netd: dnssd_clientstub DNSServiceProcessResult called with invalid DNSServiceRef 0xb3029070 FFFFFFFF DDDDDDDD

08-24 08:47:55.754 455-1483/? D/MDnsDS: controlSocket shows revent= 1

    MDnsSdListener::Monitor got 1

    MDnsSdListener::Monitor poll rescanning - size=15, live=1

    Going to poll with pollCount 2

08-24 08:47:55.756 455-1484/? D/MDnsDS: getAddrInfo(22, (null) 0, actual-device-name.local.)

08-24 08:47:55.757 455-1484/? D/MDnsDS: startMonitoring 22

08-24 08:47:55.758 455-1484/? D/MDnsDS: triggering rescan

    getAddrInfo successful

08-24 08:47:55.758 455-1483/? D/MDnsDS: Monitor poll got data pollCount = 2, 1

    controlSocket shows revent= 1

    MDnsSdListener::Monitor got 1

    MDnsSdListener::Monitor poll rescanning - size=15, live=2

    Going to poll with pollCount 3

    Monitor poll got data pollCount = 3, 1

    Monitor found [1](https://github.com/watson/bonjour).revents = 1 - calling ProcessResults

    getAddrInfo succeeded for 22: 22 "actual-device-name.local." 120 192.168.8.243

    controlSocket shows revent= 0

    Going to poll with pollCount 3

08-24 08:47:55.766 19492-19583/com.tsi.fitpro D/ZeroConf: Service was resolved.

08-24 08:47:55.766 455-1484/? D/MDnsDS: Stopping getaddrinfo with ref 0xb300c52c

08-24 08:47:55.766 19492-19583/com.tsi.fitpro D/ZeroConf: actual-device-name

08-24 08:47:55.766 455-1484/? D/MDnsDS: freeServiceRef 22
    triggering rescan

08-24 08:47:55.766 19492-19583/com.tsi.fitpro D/ZeroConf: 3603

08-24 08:47:55.767 455-1483/? D/MDnsDS: Monitor poll got data pollCount = 3, 2

    Monitor found [1](https://github.com/watson/bonjour).revents = 32 - calling ProcessResults

08-24 08:47:55.767 455-1483/? W//system/bin/netd: dnssd_clientstub DNSServiceProcessResult called with invalid DNSServiceRef 0xb3029070 FFFFFFFF DDDDDDDD

08-24 08:47:55.767 455-1483/? D/MDnsDS: controlSocket shows revent= 1

08-24 08:47:55.768 455-1483/? D/MDnsDS: MDnsSdListener::Monitor got 1

    MDnsSdListener::Monitor poll rescanning - size=15, live=1

    Going to poll with pollCount 2

08-24 08:47:55.770 455-1482/? D/EnterpriseController: netId is 0

08-24 08:47:55.770 455-1482/? D/DnsProxyListener: DNSDBG::dns by addr af 2

08-24 08:47:55.779 455-1482/? D/EnterpriseController: netId is 0

08-24 08:47:55.779 455-1482/? D/DnsProxyListener: DNSDBG::dns addrinfo af 0

08-24 08:47:55.784 19492-19583/com.tsi.fitpro D/ZeroConf: actual-device-name.lan

    preparing to send resolved service to Cordova.
08-24 08:47:55.785 19492-19583/com.tsi.fitpro D/ZeroConf: Resolved service was sent to Cordova.**

The only difference I really see is
`finding emulator-name._telnet._tcp.local. at LaptopName.:3603` and
`finding actual-device-name._telnet._tcp.local. at actual-device-name.local.:3603`
LaptopName, being part of the domain, does not have .local at the end like the real device. Could this be tripping up Android?